# Using an error as a condition in an if/then statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm working on a knn function.  Within it, I already have a function that will return the indices of the k-nearest neighbors for a given data point, when that point is compared to the data set.

Now, I'm trying to get the actual classifier function to work but I'm having trouble with an if/then statement.  There's no weighting to the nearest neighbors so it's a majority vote and as such, calculating the mode should do it.

However, since "k" can be an even number, there's a possibility of a tie, in which case, the nearest neighbor "wins" the vote.

So I'm basically trying to code the following:

if the mode exists/'statistics.mode()' does not produce an error, then the doc will be classified by the mode

else, the doc will be classified by the nearest neighbor.

TIA for any help!
Here's the code I have

```
 def getPrediction(indices_of_nearest_neighbors, training_labels):

    # get vector of "votes"
    nearest_Y = training_labels.iloc[indices_of_nearest_neighbors, 1].values     

    if statistics.mode(nearest_Y) ##does not throw an error:
        doc_classification=statistics.mode(nearest_Y)

    else doc_classification= training_labels.iloc[closest_neighbor,1]

    return doc_classification
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3.8 `statistics.mode` no longer throws an error when there's more than one mode, it just returns the first one.

Comment: First of all, thanks everyone for the quick response.  Quick question to @Barmar.  So if my array of indices have already been sorted such that the 'closest' one is first, I don't need an if/then, or a try/except (as suggested below) because it will just return label of the first one in my array, right?  (Hope that makes sense)

Comment: That's how it works in 3.8. Earlier versions throw the error.

Answer (score 2):

`try/except` are used to handle errors.

```
try:
    doc_classification = statistics.mode(nearest_Y)
except StatisticsError:
    doc_classification = training_labels.iloc[closest_neighbor,1]
```

Note that this will stop working if you upgrade to Python 3.8. You'll need to use `statistics.multimode()` and explicitly check if it returns more than one result.

```
mode = statistics.multimode(nearest_Y)
if len(mode) = 1:
    doc_classification = mode
else:
    doc_classification = training_labels.iloc[closest_neighbor,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getPrediction(indices_of_nearest_neighbors, training_labels):
    nearest_Y = training_labels.iloc[indices_of_nearest_neighbors, 1].values     
    try:
        return statistics.mode(nearest_Y) 
    except:
        return training_labels.iloc[closest_neighbor,1]
```

Replaced the if statement with a try...except

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `try-except` to catch the error:

```
def getPrediction(indices_of_nearest_neighbors, training_labels):

    # get vector of "votes"
    nearest_Y = training_labels.iloc[indices_of_nearest_neighbors, 1].values     

    try:
        ##does not throw an error:
        doc_classification=statistics.mode(nearest_Y)
    except Exception:
        doc_classification= training_labels.iloc[closest_neighbor,1]

    return doc_classification
```

You will want to catch the specific exception thrown by `mode()`, so you will need to change `Exception` to whatever that is.

Generally it's bad practice to catch general exceptions, as you may not be able to know what actually caused the exception, and it will go unnoticed.